# Validate and parsing JSON with Argonaut

Tags: json, scala, argonaut

I need parse some JSON into Scala instance or into error JSON.

For example if I have next JSON:
`{"user":"us","password":"pass"}`
and I have constraint that `"user"` shouldn't be less than 3. And then I should get next error JSON:
`{"user":"us", "_error_user":"Username length shouldn't be less than 3","password":"pass"}`

But for JSON `{"user":"user","password":"pass"}` I should get some Scala instanse like `User("user","pass")`.

Is it possible using Argonaut?

Comment: Why not parse first and validate afterwards?

Comment: @RexKerr it is no mater wich order will be. I need a way to append error messages to original object like a fields as ```_error_fieldname```. I'm novice in Scala so I will appreciate any example of how to do it.

Comment: Have you checked this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29596564/scalaz-validation-with-argonaut ?

Comment: @mfirry It is not what i want. I need to map errors to json fileds.